# Как для dataframe с помощью apply создать и последовательно наполнить 4 столбца?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image: итоговый результат]Как для dataframe с помощью apply создать и последовательно наполнить 4 столбца?

## новичок в python

сейчас поступаю таким образом.

```
df['клик на more'] = df['тег'].apply(statMore_list)
df['клик на address'] = df['тег'].apply(statAddress_list)
df['клик на map'] = df['тег'].apply(statMap_list)
df['клик на name'] = df['тег'].apply(statByUrl)
```

функция statMore_list()
*(Функции statAddress_list, statMap_list, statByUr выглядят аналогично, меняется лишь условие в конце цикла)*:

```
def statMore_list (i):
    
    API_URL = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data'
    
    params_func = {
    
                'date1': start_date,
    
                'date2': end_date,
    
                'id': id_metrika,
    
                'dimensions': 'ym:s:paramsLevel2',
    
                'metrics': 'ym:s:visits',
    
                'oauth_token': token,
    
                'filters': "ym:s:paramsLevel1=='listitem' AND ym:s:startURL=@'{}'".format(i)
    }
    
    d = requests.get(API_URL, params = params_func)
    d = d.json()
    
    for i in d['data']:
        if i['dimensions'][0]['name'] == 'more_list':
            more_list = i['metrics'][0]
            print(more_list)
            return more_list
```

по сути я делаю 3 лишних запроса к api, потому что все данные можно получить при одном ответе и заполнить ими dataframe.
но как это сделать пока не могу сообразить.

Попробовал переделать функцию таким образом:

```
def checkFunction (i):
    if i['dimensions'][0]['name'] == 'name_list':
        name_list = i['metrics'][0]
        #print(name_list)
        return name_list
    
    if i['dimensions'][0]['name'] == 'more_list':
        more_list = i['metrics'][0]
        #print(more_list)
        return more_list
    
    if i['dimensions'][0]['name'] == 'address_list':
        address_list = i['metrics'][0]
        #print(address_list)
        return address_list
    
    if i['dimensions'][0]['name'] == 'map_list':
        map_list = i['metrics'][0]
        #print(map_list)
        return map_list

def statByUrl (i):
    
    API_URL = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data'

    params_func = {

                'date1': start_date,

                'date2': end_date,

                'id': id_metrika,

                'dimensions': 'ym:s:paramsLevel2',

                'metrics': 'ym:s:visits',

                'oauth_token': token,

                'filters': "ym:s:paramsLevel1=='listitem' AND ym:s:startURL=@'{}'".format(i)
    }
    
    d = requests.get(API_URL, params = params_func)
    d = d.json()
    pprint(d)
    
    for k in d['data']:
        checkFunction(k)
```

Но дальше все равно не понимаю как в apply создать 4 столбца и наполнять их.

ответ api:

```
{'data': [{'dimensions': [{'name': 'position'}], 'metrics': [15741.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'referer'}], 'metrics': [15741.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'name_list'}], 'metrics': [7322.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'more_list'}], 'metrics': [5374.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'address_list'}], 'metrics': [4050.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'map_list'}], 'metrics': [3361.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'icon_price'}], 'metrics': [119.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'icon_photo'}], 'metrics': [49.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'icon_feedback'}], 'metrics': [30.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'icon_comments'}], 'metrics': [23.0]},
          {'dimensions': [{'name': 'icon_videos'}], 'metrics': [1.0]}],
 'data_lag': 86,
 'max': [15741.0],
 'min': [1.0],
 'query': {'attribution': 'Last',
           'auto_group_size': '1',
           'currency': 'RUB',
           'date1': '2018-02-01',
           'date2': '2018-04-16',
           'dimensions': ['ym:s:paramsLevel2'],
           'filters': "ym:s:paramsLevel1=='listitem' AND "
                      "ym:s:startURL=@'/***********/'",
           'group': 'Week',
           'ids': [***********],
           'limit': 100,
           'metrics': ['ym:s:visits'],
           'offline_window': '21',
           'offset': 1,
           'quantile': '50',
           'sort': ['-ym:s:visits']},
 'sample_share': 1.0,
 'sample_size': 767118,
 'sample_space': 767118,
 'sampled': False,
 'total_rows': 11,
 'total_rows_rounded': False,
 'totals': [15741.0]}
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных и то что вы хотите получить на выходе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Comment: Вы показали что вы хотите получить на выходе - это треть правильного ответа. Если приведете пример `d` (в виде текста - так, чтобы можно было скопировать) после `d = d.json()`, то вероятность того, что вам ответят резко возрастет ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы распарсить данный в вопросе словарь в DataFrame:

```
In [108]: data = {x['dimensions'][0]['name']:x['metrics'] for x in d['data']}

In [109]: data
Out[109]:
{'position': [15741.0],
 'referer': [15741.0],
 'name_list': [7322.0],
 'more_list': [5374.0],
 'address_list': [4050.0],
 'map_list': [3361.0],
 'icon_price': [119.0],
 'icon_photo': [49.0],
 'icon_feedback': [30.0],
 'icon_comments': [23.0],
 'icon_videos': [1.0]}

In [110]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
   address_list  icon_comments  icon_feedback  icon_photo  icon_price  icon_videos  map_list  more_list  name_list  position  referer
0        4050.0           23.0           30.0        49.0       119.0          1.0    3361.0     5374.0     7322.0   15741.0  15741.0
```

Comment: спасибо, с этим подходом все получилось.

Comment: Легко отвечать на вопросы когда четко понятно что из чего и как надо получить - это я про примеры входных и выходных данных... ;)